# Not able to sign JAR file

Tags: java

i am trying to sign a jar file i am using following commands

1. del finger.jar
2. jar xvf FDxSDKPro.jar
3. jar xvf plugin.jar
4. jar xvf mysql.jar
5. javac -deprecation finger\ *.java
6. jar cvf finger.jar SecuGen\FDxSDKPro\jni*.class finger*.class org\gjt\mm\mysql*.class  netscape\javascript*.* com\mysql\jdbc*.*
7. jarsigner -keystore store -storepass storepass -keypass keypassword finger.jar storeali

I got message jar signed... but when i try to run it as applet in html its show message that .

**an unsigned application from the location below is requesting permission to run**

Comment: This post may provide some assistance.. https://www.java.com/en/download/help/signedjar_dialog.xml

Comment: i added cmd jar i finger.jar before 7. jarsigner  to create index in jar file

Comment: You haven't deployed the signed version of the .jar file correctly, or the unsigned version is being cached somewhere.

Comment: i clear java cache and browser cache as well. and used that newly created jar file

Comment: I tried on different Pc as well